# Spark 1.6 extract month, dayofyear from timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm using Spark 1.6 by Scala.

I have a dataframe with a timestamp column. How can I generate a new column with dayofweek?

Answer (score 1):

solved.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{from_unixtime, unix_timestamp}

data.select(from_unixtime(
  unix_timestamp($"time", "MM/dd/yyyy"), "EEEEE").alias("dow"))
```